# Adding additional text fields and image upload to a Page?

Tags: admin, metabox

I have a contact page:

[image]

I would like to add an additional text field below the text editor and another image upload button. And then display it in the template as something like this:

```
<?php echo get_field('address')?>
<?php echo get_field('photo')?>
```

Is there an easy way of doing this on WordPress 3.5+?

Comment: There gotta be dozens of examples here in [wordpress.se], have you searched? `add_meta_box`? By the way, ain't `get_field` an Advanced Custom Fields function? Voting to close as [NARQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

Comment: OP probably came across an example using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) if he mentionned `get_field`.